# How do I know the detail about specific R object?

Tags: r

for example

```
data <- read.csv ("data.csv")
a <- mean(data)
b <- sd(data)
```

and I save the workspace, and then quit. 
Later, I open this workspace and forget what a and b were.
I want R to show me that a is mean of the data and b is standard deviation of the data.

How do I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: You look at the history?  Other than that there is nothing stored within R that tells you how the data came to be...

Comment: Um, you could give your variables sensible names, like `mean_data` instead of `a`. Otherwise, there's no real way to "annotate" objects in R.

Comment: I was hoping to find some kind of function of R which does something similar to how history tab of Matlab help users....

Comment: Don't save your workspace; recreate your objects from a script.

Answer (score 4):

A suggestion is to use the script feature of the R environment, rather than typing directly commands in the console.

The idea is that you can type commands, comments and even gibberish text (stuff that doesn't conform to R syntax),  in a `script window`, and using Ctrl-R (or one of `Run` commands from the `Edit` menu) you send the the current line, or whatever portion of the text that is currently selected, to the `R Console window`  (just like if had typed it directly there).

In this fashion, you can:

- add voluminous comments as to the nature of the variables that you create
- save the script along with the environment or independently.

In addition to implicitly saving a memory of the genesis of the variables, the scripts have several advantages, in particular they can save a lot of typing and they can also allow to recreate everything "from scratch", verbatim or with a few modifications.

Answer (score 4):

You could always store some attributes with your data like so:

```
x <- 1:10
a <- mean(x)
attr(a,"info") <- "mean of x"

> a
[1] 5.5
attr(,"info")
[1] "mean of x"

> attributes(a)
$info
[1] "mean of x"
```

An alternative noted by @mnel below is to use `comment`. These will not be printed by default but can be accessed later in a similar fashion like so:

```
comment(a) <- "mean of x"

> comment(a)
[1] "mean of x"
```

Comment: `comment(a) <- 'mean of x' ` is slightly less typing.

Comment: @mnel - never heard of `comment` until now - i'll edit that into the answer.

Comment: It is does the equivalent of  `attr(x ,'comment') <- 'blah`

Answer (score 3):

In general you won't be able to find out how an object was created from the object itself. Some `object` types will have a `call` element that may save the `call` used to create them.

`lm` objects have this property.

eg

```
dd <- data.frame(y=runif(10), x= rnorm(10))
model <- lm(y~x,dd)
model$call
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dd)
```

In this case `mean` and `sd` will not as they will return atomic vectors.

You could look at the `history` to see if you  can find commands that created them (this is not ideal, it is dependent your IDE and how some environmental variables are set up).

Rstudio has a history tab that shows some subset of the previous commands called within a project.

You may also be able to press the up key (this works in the RGui on windows at least), to scroll through the previously called commands.

These commands based on the history require that you used the same computer and version of `R`.

Reproducible research or literate programming are the best ways to overcome these issues.